# Analysis techinque in proving $e^x>1+x$

Tags: real-analysis

To prove that $e^x>1+x$, for all $x<0$. If I try to write $e^x$ as $1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3$, for some $\xi\in (x,0)$. Then I get $e^x-(1+x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3$. How do I show that $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3$ is necessarily positive? I'd tried thinking for a long time, but can't find the way. Can't it be done by using Taylor to exactly order $3$??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the shorter Taylor expansion, $e^x=1+x+\frac{e^{\xi}}{2!}x^2$ where $\xi$ is between $0$ and $x$, the proof is straightforward.

However, if you would like to consider the longer expansion $e^x=1+x+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3$, it suffices to show that for $x\in (-1,0)$,
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3=\frac{x^2}{6}\left(3+xe^{\xi}\right)>\frac{x^2}{6}\left(3+x\right)>0$$
which holds. Note that for $x\leq-1$, $e^x>0\geq 1+x$.

Comment: I know that. But I wonder if this can be done with order $3$(like me), or order $4,5,6,7$... etc?

Comment: Yes. Note that it suffices to show that $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3>0$ just in $-1<x<0$ (otherwise $e^x>1+x$ is trivially true).

Comment: Because for $x\leq-1$, $e^x>0\geq 1+x$.

Comment: Thanks! I see. But if we only look at the expression $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3$, can it be shown that this is greater than $0$ outside $-1<x<0$? The values of $x$ lower than $-1$, will results a "very negative term" $x^3$, however, the $x^2$ will save it(from letting the whole expression begin $\leq 0$). How can we show that?

Comment: @Eric See my P.S.

Comment: @Eric I don't think so, we just know that $x<\xi<0$ and we are not able to control the positive coefficient of $x^3$ ($x^3\to -\infty$ faster than $x^2/2\to +\infty$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: Hmm.. it is weird that we are easy to see $e^x-(1+x)>0$ for $x<-1$, and we know that $e^x-(1+x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3$ for all $x$, however, on the other hand, we are unable to show that $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3>0$ for $x<-1$. What is the mysterious logic behind this? ...(edited) Wait, I see. It is due to $\xi$ is always changing.

Comment: @Eric Note that $e^{x}\to 0$ as $x\to-\infty$ and any polynomial expansion $P(x)$ will tend to $\pm \infty$ (depending on the degree). It is a quite bad approximation isn't it?

Comment: typo in $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3=\frac{x^2}{6}\left(2+xe^{\xi}\right)$?

Comment: @Eric Thanks! Now it should be correct.

Comment: Very clear, I understand. The key point is that $\xi$ is depends on $x$, so it should be very careful when dealing with the inequality $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3>0$: not only the coefficient of $x^3$ in indeterminate, but also the $\xi$ here must satisfies the doctrine $x<\xi<0$. The root of the inequality is $0,0,\frac{-3}{e^{\xi}}$.

Comment: .. So it may appear that the inequality $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3>0$ become **false** when $x$ is very "negative", say $x=-99999$, whatsoever, but this is not exactly the fact! When $x$ is very "negative", the point $\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}$ also depends on it(mutable!), and probably getting very negative too. So there's a logic trap inside it. One should deal it very carefully.

Comment: So it is best divide into some cases. As your way, we dividing into the case $(-\infty,-1]$ and $(-1,0)$. For the latter case, we can confirm that the inequality $\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{e^{\xi}}{3!}x^3>0$ is true. For the former case, this inequality is dangerous to use, so we this time directly look at the expression $e^x-(1+x)$, knowing that it's also true.

Comment: @Eric Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the approximation is the easiest way to go.

Rather, I would take a look at the function $f(x)=e^x - (1+x)$ and prove that the function has exactly one minimum which is acchieved at $x=0$.

Comment: I know, but I see many exercise of proving inequalities that uses MVT but not standard procedure of relative extremum, etc.

Comment: I want to ask that, is every inequalities problem that can be solve by the techique of MVT or Taylor, can therotically also be turn into a solution by the analysis of extremum? (corresponding to most Calculus textbook chapter. 3 or 4)

Comment: @Eric Well yes, because the statement $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$ is equivalent to "the minimum of $f(x)-g(x)$ is greater than $0$". But that doesn't mean translating into extremums is always the best idea...

Comment: Thanks. When the function is pretty ugly, would there be some chance that it is possible to prove via MVT, but not possible to prove using the "systematic" way(i.e., chapter 3 or 4 in most calculsu books)? I ask this question, because I'm afraid of proving inequalties by MVT(nightmare!), but feel quite comfortable and natural to prove them by  the systematic way. I'm afraid that I can't always prove them by that way. :(

Comment: @Eric It' possible, sure. And the only way to get the intuition it takes to know which way to try is practice, practice, practice.

Comment: If you're available, can you mention one inqualities that can't be prove via the "systematic way". I'm seeking for that instance. But if you don't have a book at hand or can't recall one, it's ok. :)

Answer (score 1):

If $x< 0,$ then $\int_x^0 e^t\,dt < \int_x^0 1\,dt,$ simply because $e^t < 1$ on $[x,0).$ Evaluate these integrals to see $1-e^{x} < -x,$ and the inequality follows.

Answer (score 0):

For $u\in(0,1)$,

$$u-\ln u=1-\int_u^1\left(1-\frac1t\right)dt> 1$$

Then change $u=e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

For $x<0$, $e^0=1+0$ and $(e^x)'<(1+x)'$. Starting from a common point, $e^x$ decreases slower than $1+x$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \lt 0$ , $x$ real.

$f(x):= e^x$;

Mean Value Theorem:

$\dfrac{f(x) - f(0)}{x} =  $

$\dfrac{e^x -1 }{x} = f'(t)$ where ,

$t\in (x,0)$ for $x<0$.

Let $c: = e^t.$

Note :  $0 \lt c \lt 1.$

Hence: $e^x  = cx +1 > 1x +1.$

(Recall that $x\lt 0$.)